# htaccess How to redirect old dynamic url to the new one

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, dynamic, hyperlink

My web uses links which are dynamic set by code in htaccess (bellow):

```
RewriteRule ^(.*),(.*),([a-z0-9-_.]+),([a-z0-9-_.]+),([a-z0-9-_.]+)$ $4.php?n=$1&z=$2&t=$3&v=$5 [L,NC,NS,NE]
```

In effect links looks like this (example):

```
www.mypage.com/$1,$2,$3,$4,$5
```

I want to redirect dynamic links in htaccess from old to new one which will have a structure like this (without $5 parameter):

```
www.mypage.com/$4/$1-$2/$3
```

Redirection is necessarily especially for redirect old links availble in search engines to new one.

Thanks for a help.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have an Apache instance to hand to test against just now but off the top of my head something like this should work:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*),(.*),([a-z0-9-_.]+),([a-z0-9-_.]+),([a-z0-9-_.]+)$ $4/$1-$2/$3 [L,R=301]

RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9-_.]+)/(.*)-(.*)/([a-z0-9-_.]+)$ $1.php?n=$2&z=$3&t=$4 [L,NC,NS,NE]
```

The first rewrite redirects your old URLs (`1,2,3,4,5`) to the new ones (`4/1-2/3`) using a 301 to tell search engines to drop the old URLs in favour of the new ones.

The second rewrite takes the new format and maps it to your actual script.

Note how the 5th param is dropped when transforming old to new.